# Malformed Packet on Mosquitto

Tags: mqtt, esp32, mosquitto, gsm

I am trying  to connect to my `mosquitto` broker on `esp32` with `GSM` using `pubsubclient` but sometimes it disconnects to broker with detail *malformed packet*.

```
2023-08-30T13:43:14: Client client_id disconnected due to malformed packet.
```

I have this dump at command on device and it display like this :

```
13:31:08.540 > DATA ACCEPT:0,2
13:31:08.540 > AT+CIPSEND=0,2
13:31:08.568 > 
13:31:08.568 > 
13:31:08.570 >  
13:31:08.604 > DATA ACCEPT:0,2
13:31:08.604 > AT+CIPRXGET=4,0
13:31:08.660 > 
13:31:08.660 > +CIPRXGET: 4,0,0
13:31:08.660 > 
13:31:08.660 > OK
13:31:08.660 > AT+CIPSTATUS=0
13:31:08.755 > 
13:31:08.755 > +CIPSTATUS: 0,0,"TCP","13.228.184.92","80","CONNECTED"
13:31:08.760 > 
13:31:08.760 > OK
13:31:09.762 > AT+CIPRXGET=4,0
13:31:09.780 > 
13:31:09.781 > +CIPRXGET: 1,0
13:31:09.817 > 
13:31:09.818 > +CIPRXGET: 4,0,370
13:31:09.818 > 
13:31:09.818 > OK
13:31:09.818 > AT+CIPSTATUS=0
13:31:09.917 > 
13:31:09.918 > +CIPSTATUS: 0,0,"TCP","BROKER IP","80","REMOTE CLOSING"
```

I have limited some possibilities that are causing the problem.

- After failing to connect to broker I try to connect to server using `http` and it connected without problems.
- Tried using public broker like `hivemq` for a short time and it does not have a problem.
- I have tried to connect to broker using another device (`Android`, `mqttx`, etc.) and they run well also.

Comment: Why do you think connecting via http is meaningful? Is the broker also configured to accept WebSocket connections on port 80?

Comment: Is there any way you could capture the actual packets on either side? Your log tells us that packets were exchanged, but not their contents. Does it disconnect right away, or does it take some time before it does?

Comment: @hardillb it just to confirm that there is no problem on the sim module. the connection is stable

Comment: Also, what protocol are you actually using? MQTT? HTTP? With or without TLS? The log above shows port 80...

Comment: @jcaron im using mqtt without using tls

Comment: port 80 is meant to another function that to identify is client can connect with another protocol

Comment: So what is the relevance of the log you provided which apparently deals with a connection on port 80?

Comment: "sometimes it disconnect to broker"  - Are you saying that it works sometimes and then disconnects randomly ?

Comment: yes it is,it disconnect randomly